# Changing the caret color in silverlight 2

Tags: silverlight-2.0

I have a textbox that has a black background, I want to change its caret color to white.How do i achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't believe this is possible. There is no property on the `TextBox` to perform this and the default template for the `TextBox` provides no means of manipulating the content and therefore, the caret. I believe that this is because the content is provided through the `XcpImports` class.

As far as I can ascertain, `XcpImports` is the abstraction layer between the Silverlight plug-in and the operating system (Windows, OS/X). Therefore, you cannot actually get at the real text box to manipulate the caret unless Silverlight provides a route to do it, which it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in Silverlight 2 (as your post is flagged), but for future reference (and others landing on this page from Google as I did) in Silverlight 3 the TextBox has a CaretBrush property...